# Having problem with installing JDK 7 and 8

Tags: java, jdk

I wanted to install JDK 7 and 8 on my system and I followed bellow post:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16263556/installing-java-7-on-ubuntu

But now, when I enter the:

```
sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-installer
```

I face with following error:

```
sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-installer
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
oracle-java7-installer is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 135 not upgraded.
3 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up oracle-java7-installer (7u65+7u60arm-0~webupd8~2) ...
Downloading Oracle Java 7...
--2014-07-26 12:37:13--  http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/7u65-b17/jdk-7u65-linux-x64.tar.gz
Resolving download.oracle.com (download.oracle.com)... 63.85.36.73, 63.85.36.40
Connecting to download.oracle.com (download.oracle.com)|63.85.36.73|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Moved Temporarily
Location: https://edelivery.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/7u65-b17/jdk-7u65-linux-x64.tar.gz [following]
--2014-07-26 12:37:15--  https://edelivery.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/7u65-b17/jdk-7u65-linux-x64.tar.gz
Resolving edelivery.oracle.com (edelivery.oracle.com)... 23.73.246.140
Connecting to edelivery.oracle.com (edelivery.oracle.com)|23.73.246.140|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 503 Service Unavailable
2014-07-26 12:37:18 ERROR 503: Service Unavailable.

download failed
Oracle JDK 7 is NOT installed.
dpkg: error processing package oracle-java7-installer (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up oracle-java8-installer (8u11+8u6arm-1~webupd8~3) ...
Downloading Oracle Java 8...
--2014-07-26 12:37:19--  http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u11-b12/jdk-8u11-linux-x64.tar.gz
Resolving download.oracle.com (download.oracle.com)... 23.216.11.120, 23.216.11.90
Connecting to download.oracle.com (download.oracle.com)|23.216.11.120|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Moved Temporarily
Location: https://edelivery.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u11-b12/jdk-8u11-linux-x64.tar.gz [following]
--2014-07-26 12:37:21--  https://edelivery.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u11-b12/jdk-8u11-linux-x64.tar.gz
Resolving edelivery.oracle.com (edelivery.oracle.com)... 23.73.246.140
Connecting to edelivery.oracle.com (edelivery.oracle.com)|23.73.246.140|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 503 Service Unavailable
2014-07-26 12:37:24 ERROR 503: Service Unavailable.

download failed
Oracle JDK 8 is NOT installed.
dpkg: error processing package oracle-java8-installer (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of oracle-java7-set-default:
 oracle-java7-set-default depends on oracle-java7-installer; however:
  Package oracle-java7-installer is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package oracle-java7-set-default (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 oracle-java7-installer
 oracle-java8-installer
 oracle-java7-set-default
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I think my problem is coming from error 503, but how I can fix it. In addition, always when I try to install another package I face with this message. At least, how I can get rid of this message.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I too am getting this error, I tried going to the edelivery.oracle.com site to see if there was an issue there and it looks like there is:

> From https://edelivery.oracle.com/download/index.html
>
> You are experiencing a connectivity issue with the Oracle Software Delivery Cloud. Please   try to access this site again later. If you have questions, please contact Software Delivery Customer Service at edelivery_ww@oracle.com.

Although I can not find any actual status messages, it's been like this since I started trying an hour or so ago.

Edit: It would appear to be back online now (2014-07-26 10:00 UTC).